# Pyspark: Stepwise Variable Selection

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, feature-selection

Can someone tell me how do I perform stepwise variable selection in pyspark. I am currently using the mllib package of Spark 1.5.1

Comment: I have used LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS. I have currently implemented pca for my feature selection. I have about 6000 features. I would like to do something like a forward selection or backward elimination for my models now but there's no such thing in spark libraries. Is there someway I can do it? or maybe is there an integration of scikit libraries with spark?

Comment: Sorry buddy, no such thing as that in spark as of now even in versions >2.0. But you can obviously use PCA in ml (use only variables which form the first 10 principal components, say depending on explained variation) and chisqselector in mllib for selecting pertinent variables for your logistic regression model. You would never need 6000 variables for a logistic. You can also look at calculating the entropy for this.